# Flip a Bitmap image horizontally or vertically

Tags: java, android, image, matrix, android-bitmap

By using this code we can rotate an image:

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(angle);
      return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

But how can we flip an image horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Given `cx,cy` is the centre of the image:

Flip in x:

```
matrix.postScale(-1, 1, cx, cy);
```

Flip in y:

```
matrix.postScale(1, -1, cx, cy);
```

Altogether:

```
public static Bitmap createFlippedBitmap(Bitmap source, boolean xFlip, boolean yFlip) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(xFlip ? -1 : 1, yFlip ? -1 : 1, source.getWidth() / 2f, source.getHeight() / 2f);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: how do you find the center of the image ?

Comment: @MayurRokade `source.getWidth()/2f` `source.getHeight()/2f`

Answer (score 14):

Using Kotlin and extension functions:

```
// To flip horizontally:
fun Bitmap.flipHorizontally(): Bitmap {
    val matrix = Matrix().apply { postScale(-1f, 1f, width / 2f, height / 2f) }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
}

// To flip vertically:
fun Bitmap.flipVertically(): Bitmap {
    val matrix = Matrix().apply { postScale(1f, -1f, width / 2f, height / 2f) }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution! To extend the Bitmap functions. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html

Answer (score 10):

Short extension for Kotlin

```
private fun Bitmap.flip(x: Float, y: Float, cx: Float, cy: Float): Bitmap {
    val matrix = Matrix().apply { postScale(x, y, cx, cy) }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
}
```

And usage:

For horizontal flip :-

```
val cx = bitmap.width / 2f
val cy = bitmap.height / 2f
val flippedBitmap = bitmap.flip(-1f, 1f, cx, cy)
ivMainImage.setImageBitmap(flippedBitmap)
```

For vertical flip :-

```
val cx = bitmap.width / 2f
val cy = bitmap.height / 2f
val flippedBitmap = bitmap.flip(1f, -1f, cx, cy)
ivMainImage.setImageBitmap(flippedBitmap)
```

Comment: I would put the `cx` and `cy` calculation inside the `flip` method. `Matrix().apply { postScale(x, y, width / 2f, height / 2f) }` Also your `flip` method is no different to a `scale` method extension.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below codes:

```
private fun setVerticalFlip() {
    if (binding.imgReal.scaleX == 1.0f) {
        binding.imgReal.scaleX = -1.0f
    } else {
        binding.imgReal.scaleX = 1.0f
    }
}

private fun setHorizontalFlip() {
    if (binding.imgReal.scaleY == 1.0f) {
        binding.imgReal.scaleY = -1.0f
    } else {
        binding.imgReal.scaleY = 1.0f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal and vertical flips for Bitmap bms (source).

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// for horizontal flip
matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
matrix.postTranslate( bms.getWidth(),0);
// for vertical flip
matrix.setScale( 1,-1);
matrix.postTranslate( 0, bms.getHeight());
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap( bms, 0, 0, bms.getWidth(), bms.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its all about the matrix you use.  To flip it around the x axes, use [[-1,0],[0, 1]].   For the y axes, use [[1,0],[0,-1]].  The important thing here is that the absolute value of the determinant is 1, so it won't scale.  And the - basically inverses the location around the given axes.

Comment: Problem is, an x of 100 becomes an x of -100, this needs to happen around the centre of the image, not the origin.

Comment: Then translate the canvas first.

Comment: If you mean apply a translate to the matrix, then you must also translate afterwards too. i.e. you can `translate(-cx/2,-cy/2), scale, translate(cx/2,cy/2)`.